# Deploy Spark into Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm newbie in Kubernetes & Spark Environment.
I'm requested to deploy Spark inside Kubernetes so that it's can be auto Horizontal Scalling.

The problem is, I can't deploy SparkPi example from official website(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes#cluster-mode).

I've already follow the instruction, but the pods failed to execute.
Here is the explanation :

1. Already run : Kubectl proxy
   [image: Kubectl proxy]
2. When execute :

`spark-submit --master k8s://https://localhost:6445 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=xnuxer88/spark-kubernetes-bash-test-entry:v1 local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.2.jar`

Get Error : 
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi`
[image: When executing Spark-Submit]
[image: Pods Logs]

3. When I check the docker image (create the container from related image), I found the file.
   [image: File exists]

Is there any missing instruction that I forgot to follow?

Please Help.

Thank You.

Comment: I have the same problem, the saprk doc explains how to deploy spark examples (applications) on kubernetes and not the spark itself, the solution consists to build docker images from kubernetes directory of the distributed package, i built spark image form Dockerfile but i failed to run spark image inside docker container, i think there is a bug in entrypoint.sh (code exit = 1) file in the distributed package of spark. if you want you can take a look here https://github.com/tashoyan/docker-spark-submit